# No rule to make target

Tags: linux

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to create my own package. But until to catkin_make step it shows that:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/home/leddar/catkin_ws/src/leddar/readleddar/Readleddar.cpp', needed by `leddar/CMakeFiles/Readleddar.dir/readleddar/Readleddar.cpp.o'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [leddar/CMakeFiles/Readleddar.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

it's this due to I'm missing some of the important step during roscreate-pkg? Or something else?

Thank you so much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232440/no-rule-to-make-target/) by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2016-04-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-04-20**:
does the file `/home/leddar/catkin_ws/src/leddar/readleddar/Readleddar.cpp` exist? This will be easier to debug if you **edit** your question to include your CMakeLists.txt and the list of files in your package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found out my problem. it's too stupid. I just simply forget to add the executable and target to CMakeLists.txt. After I add them add in, and the problem solved.

thank you.

---

Originally posted by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) with karma: 104 on 2016-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Anukriti](https://answers.ros.org/users/79683/anukriti/) on 2021-12-22**:
Hey what do you mean by adding executable to CMakeLists? Even I am facing a similar issue

Thanks

**Comment by [marcelaaniceto](https://answers.ros.org/users/96523/marcelaaniceto/) on 2022-02-10**:
Hey what do you mean by adding executable to CMakeLists? Even I am facing a similar issue [2]
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For me it is because I forgot to modify the package.xml

---

Originally posted by [waschbaer00](https://answers.ros.org/users/34002/waschbaer00/) with karma: 41 on 2018-03-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1